# PHP timestamp format

Tags: php, format, timestamp

I never thought this will be such a pain. What is the best way to convert back this timestamp to a standard PHP timestamp that strtotime() accepts? :

> September 29, 2017, 7:16 UTC

The format is:

> date("F j, Y, G:i T")

Comment: What happens when use use `strtotime`?

Comment: It is converting fine, `$timestamp = strtotime('September 29, 2017, 7:16 UTC'); echo $timestamp; echo date("F j, Y, G:i T",$timestamp);` what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and confirmation! Indeed, there was another problem, maybe in the string i provided to strtotime. I don't know, probably the problem is in between the screen and the chair.

Answer (score 1):

Build a DateTime object first, then format it to a standard format, this will pass into strtotime.

```
$date = "September 29, 2017, 7:16 UTC";
$day = new DateTime($date);
$utc = strtotime($day->format("Y-m-d g:i A"));
```